# Reflection of power at low frequency (non-transmission line)

Tags: rf, impedance, transmission-line

Say you have a 1 kHz signal source with an impedance of 50 ohms and then connect a 100 ohm resistor between the terminals. Is the power that is reflected calculated in the same way as transmission lines (i.e reflection coefficient)?

[image]

I know that in the case of an open circuit that all the power is reflected (even for low frequency circuits) which can be measured by a directional coupler.

Comment: Yes, all the equations hold right down to DC, if you want to use them, and interpret them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes. Your resistor actually has an impedance of 100 Ω. (For 1 kHz, that's not only theoretically, but also practically true. For 10 GHz, the parasitics/geometry of the resistor means it's not actually a 100Ω termination, but that's a different story.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it applies.  It's just not used because it's more complicated than just using lumped-constant analysis.

Note that you can't *assume* that you don't have to pay attention at 1kHz: a 1kHz signal in free space has a wavelength of 300km or so, and that distance only goes down when you send it out on a real transmission line.  You'll start seeing transmission line effects from one edge of a big city to another at 1kHz, and you'll definitely see them from city to city.